# How do I remove the Input [ ] Output [ ] in a Jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

When coding in a Jupyter notebook, is it possible to disable showing the In [ ], Out [ ] next to each code cell? If not, is it possible to do when rendering the notebook using NBViewer? I'd like my notebooks to look a little nicer, so I'd like to get rid of these things. Thanks!

Comment: you will have to be more elaborate and give an example of what you are doing

Comment: Is it possible to disable the Input [ ], Output [ ] next to code cells in a notebook? And is it possible to disable them when rendering them in NBViewer?